# Compare SQL result rows with each other

Tags: sql, database, compare, resultset

I have a result set from a sql query that I need to compare to each other.

Example:

```
ID |  VALUE  |  Comment | sort | store | price
 1    test       main      des    f1       5
 2    each       sec       asc    f2       10
 3    test       main      des    f1       12
```

Now from that result set I need to only get the rows where value, comment, sort and store are the same.

like:

```
 ID |  VALUE  |  Comment | sort | store | price
  1    test       main      des     f1      5
  3    test       main      des     f1      12
```

so I need to alter the

```
select id, value, comment, sort, store, price from test.table
```

and do that matching.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

TheVagabond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SQL databases support window functions.  You can do this as:

```
select id, value, comment, sort, store, price
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by value, comment, sort, store) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I think you would want to `cnt > 1` instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

If your database does not support window functions you can try the query below:

```
select
    *
from
    (
        select
            value, comment, sort, store
        from
            test
        group by
            value, comment, sort, store
        having count(*) > 1
    ) as t
    inner join test on (
        test.value = t.value and test.sort = t.sort and test.сomment = t.сomment and test.store = t.store
    )
```

But I'd suggest you another output for "each other" comparison:

```
select
    t1.id, t2.id, t1.VALUE, t1.sort, t1.store, t1.price, t2.price
from
    test t1
    join test t2 on (t2.id > t1.id and t1.value = t2.value and t1.sort = t2.sort and t1.store = t2.store and t1.comment = t2.comment)
```